# Installing original Intel graphics driver on Hp envy laptop

Tags: laptop, windows-8.1, drivers, graphics-card

I have Hp envy 15 j100 with Intel HD 4600 graphics running Windows 8.1 64 bit. The latest driver provided by Hp is from 2014 v 10.18.10.3304. However Intel provides newer driver from 2017 v 15.36.33.4578, and when I attempted to install it, the installer warned that Hp customize the drivers and it directed me to the support page which said it is possible to install the generic [Driver](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005469/graphics-drivers.html) with risk possibility.  My question is : Is it safe to do this? and did someone tried to do similar thing?

Comment: If you want to use Windows 10 it’s your only option

Comment: @Ramhound Microsoft almost "begged" me to update to windows 10 for free a year but I was afraid since I knew that A new version of windows will be likely a buggy version at the first few months, second I heard later that windows 10 is not privacy friendly windows. And the free update year ended long time ago :)

Comment: My apologies a miss read the tag, my advice is the same though